# Equivalent conditions for a polynomial to be divisible by $(x-1)^{k+1}$

Tags: polynomials

I could prove the following assertions:

Let P be a polynomial of degree n in $\Bbb R$[X]:

a) P is divisible by $(x-1)^{k+1}$ is equivalent to P' divisible by $(x-1)^k$ and P(1) = 0.

b) Let P(1) = 0. P is divisible by $(x-1)^{k+1}$ is equivalent to $P_1$ = nP - xP' is divisible by $(x-1)^k$

Now the text of the problem asks to deduce from a) and b) that:

c) P is divisible by $(x-1)^{k+1}$ is equivalent to:

$a_0$ + $a_1$ + ... + $a_n$ = 0

$a_1$ + 2$a_2$ + ...+ n$a_n$ = 0

....

$a_1$ + $2^k$$a_2$ + ...+ $n^k$$a_n$ = 0

I can see that the first 2 equalities in the above system come from the fact that P(1) = 0 and P'(1) = 0, but was not able to deduce the other equalities. Can someone provide me a hint?
Thanks a lot.